# Login failed for user in SQL Server 2008 for Windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have two PC (both have Win7). On PC "A" I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and developed a Windows application. On PC "A" my application is running well and there is no connectivity issue.

But when I run this application on PC "B" (connected with PC "B" through LAN and able to share any file) it shows error message login failed for user'....'.

I have already make some possible solution but can't solve it.. Need help

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=WIN7-PC\PRABHAT;Initial Catalog=plproject;User ID= win7-PC\Prabhat;MultipleActiveResultsets=true
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server error log contains addtional information about failed logins. Look there and find the code that maps to the table listed here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555332

One possible issue is that you are running as a machine account that doesn't exist on machine B. You need the Windows identity to flow from one machine to another and this is typically accomplished with a domain service account. If you want it to work from machine B, you need to access it with an account machine B is aware of. Supplying the User ID is typically for SQL Server authentication, not Windows authentication. You could try adding the password and see if that works.

Here is a breakdown of SQL Connection String syntax: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: If I want to run this application more than two computers and if I can't reach to those computers then which user id I should use in my connection string?

Comment: You could use SQL Server authentication and provide the User ID and password in the connection string.

Comment: Sir I did the same. But problem is still unsolve. Please provide me details or any link for configuration and connection string.

Comment: This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562(v=sql.100).aspx) contains information on creating a SQL Server login and and this [one](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) contains information on connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable TCP/IP for cross machine SQL SERVER access. Just follow below mentioned steps to ensure whether it is enable or disabled.

1. Click on window start menu.
2. Navigate to Microsoft **SQL SERVER => Configuration Tool => SQL
   Server 2008 Configuration Manager**.
3. In Opened window Navigate to **SQL SERVER Network Configuration =>
   `Protocols for <MSSQLSERVER>`** (Protocols for your SQL server
   instance name)
4. Check Whether **TCP/IP** is enabled or not.

[image]